# need to Loop only part of imacro code

Tags: loops, imacros

I have a task where I need to extract result for every loop and I need to save it to file using imacros. How can I loop only few lines.

URL GOTO=https://www.google.co.in/

'I am reading from file and filling form here
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:phone CONTENT={{!var1}}

' taking reasult from form and need to save it to file
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:dataDiv EXTRACT=TXT

' My motto is I need to save the extracted data into single file. but it is saving in one file for one loop.

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=UbErAcNtS_{{!NOW:ddmmyy_hhnnss}}.csv

WAIT SECONDS=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to save the extracted data into a single file, just remove '_hhnnss' in the file name:

```
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=UbErAcNtS_{{!NOW:ddmmyy}}.csv
```